# Расширения VS Code и пакеты npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, eslint

Прошу прощения за наивный вопрос - я новичок в js. Искал, где мог, но объяснения не нашел. Видать, слишком простой вопрос, что должен быть понятен "по умолчанию". Однако, оным остался озадачен, оконфужен окончательно!
Вопрос про расширения VS Code и пакеты npm, в частности ESLint:
1.Установить расширение ESLint в VS Code, это не тоже самое, что установить пакет npm ("npm install eslint --save-dev")?
2.Надо сделать и то, и другое?
3.Они взаимно дополняют друг друга?
4.И, в целом, в чем разница между установкой расширения VS Code и соответствующим (одноименным) пакетом npm?
5.Спасибо!

Comment: Это равносильно установить расширение с/с++ но не иметь компилятора.

Comment: Понятно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установка пакета в npm -  это то, с чем Ваш код сможет работать.  eslint позволит Вам с командрой строки запускать проверку кода.

Одноименный плагин для VSCode (не только для eslint)  - это обычно красивая оболочка, что бы было приятно видеть результаты прямо в коде (в редакторе кода), что бы был красиво подчеркнут код, поменять настройки и тому подобное. Обычно такие плагины для редактора не включают в себя одноименный nmp модуль. А часто совсем не связаны между собой.

Если почитать описания плагина, то все стает на свои места

> The extension **uses** the ESLint library installed in the opened workspace folder. If the folder doesn't provide one the extension **looks for a global install version**. If you haven't installed ESLint either locally or globally do so by running npm install eslint in the workspace folder for a local install or npm install -g eslint for a global install.

Короткий перевод - ищет в текущем проекте, если нет - глобально, если и там нет - устновите сами.

Короткий ответ на 1,2,3 - да.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: можно просто нажать галочку и стрелочку вверх

Comment: ))) Принято! Но нолик остался?! Спасибо Вам большое!